# How to split long xml file into multiple separate xml files in seperate subdirectories

Tags: xml

So I have multiple .meta files which basicly acts like .XML files. Now I have multiple files which are very long and complex and I wish to separate them into multiple .meta files, each in their own subdirectory with a specified name grabbed from a specific tag in the .meta file. Here is an example of the .meta file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CVehicleModelInfo__InitDataList>
    <residentTxd>vehshare</residentTxd>
    <residentAnims />
    <InitDatas>
        <Item>
            <modelName>car1</modelName>
            <txdName>car1</txdName>
            <handlingId>drifthandling</handlingId>
            <gameName>car1</gameName>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <modelName>car2</modelName>
            <txdName>car2</txdName>
            <handlingId>drifthandling</handlingId>
            <gameName>car2</gameName>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <modelName>car3</modelName>
            <txdName>car3</txdName>
            <handlingId>drifthandling</handlingId>
            <gameName>car3</gameName>
        </Item>
    </InitDatas>
    <txdRelationships>
        <Item>
            <parent>vehshare</parent>
            <child>car1</child>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <parent>vehshare</parent>
            <child>car2</child>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <parent>vehshare</parent>
            <child>car3</child>
        </Item>
    </txdRelationships>
</CVehicleModelInfo__InitDataList>
```

Now I want to split this long file into multiple separate files, each in their own folder by the name of the content `<modelName>car</modelName>`

Here should be the result:

`/car1/vehicles.meta`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CVehicleModelInfo__InitDataList>
    <residentTxd>vehshare</residentTxd>
    <residentAnims />
    <InitDatas>
        <Item>
            <modelName>car1</modelName>
            <txdName>car1</txdName>
            <handlingId>drifthandling</handlingId>
            <gameName>car1</gameName>
        </Item>
    </InitDatas>
    <txdRelationships>
        <Item>
            <parent>vehshare</parent>
            <child>car1</child>
        </Item>
    </txdRelationships>
</CVehicleModelInfo__InitDataList>
```

`/car2/vehicles.meta`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CVehicleModelInfo__InitDataList>
    <residentTxd>vehshare</residentTxd>
    <residentAnims />
    <InitDatas>
        <Item>
            <modelName>car2</modelName>
            <txdName>car2</txdName>
            <handlingId>drifthandling</handlingId>
            <gameName>car2</gameName>
        </Item>
    </InitDatas>
    <txdRelationships>
        <Item>
            <parent>vehshare</parent>
            <child>car2</child>
        </Item>
    </txdRelationships>
</CVehicleModelInfo__InitDataList>
```

Etc... Etc...

I'm pretty new to both C# and/or other coding languages so might want to keep it simple. I know how to make an executable with C# LINQ to XML at least, so that might help with this specific goal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I've partly got it to work after a lot of learning/testing but it's not fully what I wanted to achieve. I've managed to add the whole `<Item>` to a new document, each in their own folder by the name of `<modelName>`. Here is my current snippet:

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string strFileName;
            string strSeq;
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();             // The input file
            doc.Load("C:\\Users\\willi\\Desktop\\mad_cars\\newapp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\vehicles.meta");
            XmlNodeList nl = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//InitDatas/Item");
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Process");



            foreach (XmlNode n in nl)
            {
                strSeq = n.InnerText;

                string modelName = n["modelName"].InnerText;
                Console.WriteLine("Creating directories for each vehicle");
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\willi\\Desktop\\mad_cars\\newapp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\vehicles\\" + modelName);


                XmlDocument outdoc = new XmlDocument();      // Create the outdoc xml document
                XmlNode targetNode = outdoc.CreateElement("InitDatas"); // Create a separate node to hold the Animal element

                targetNode = outdoc.ImportNode(n, true);     // Bring over that Animal

                outdoc.ImportNode(targetNode, true);         // place the node n into outdoc
                outdoc.AppendChild(targetNode);              // AppendChild to make it stick

                strFileName = "vehicles.meta";
                //outdoc.Save(Console.Out); Console.WriteLine();
                outdoc.Save("C:\\Users\\willi\\Desktop\\mad_cars\\newapp\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\vehicles\\" + modelName + "\\" + strFileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Saved files");
            }
        }
```

Now I'm missing the

```xml
    <txdRelationships>
        <Item>
            <parent>vehshare</parent>
            <child>car2</child>
        </Item>
    </txdRelationships>
```

part, which I have no clue of how to add to the same document.